# Sign in with LinkedIn, SDK for Android, Sample application error

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-ios-sdk

I would like to try feature "integrate Sign In with LinkedIn".

I follow instructions and i download latest version ( Mobile SDK for Android 1.1.4) from:

https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk

Then i import and build project into Android Studio.

When i execute SDK for Android Sample App i obtain this screenshot:

http://i64.tinypic.com/35hpvyb.png

Any help will be appreciated. Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself.

The problem was i didn´t follow (ignore) step "Associate your Android app with your LinkedIn app"

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

1) Create an application
2) Signing Your Application, generating a debug key hash value.
3) Configure the values: In the Mobile->Android Settings->"Package Name & Package Hash" section of your LinkedIn application's configuration, add your application's package and hash values

That´s all. Sorry for such a dumb question... ;)